# Why does my UIToolBar scroll with my UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, objective-c

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to build my view. Everything works out great up to the point where I need to insert a UIToolBar into my view. The tableView is placed where I expected it to be placed. The UIToolBar on the other hand, scrolls up and down with the table, it doesn't remain fixed as it should. It also looks rather odd when put on the screen -- I'm guessing because the calculation to place it isn't right? Attached to this question is a screenshot as well as the code I've used to build this. Thanks for your help in spotting out what I'm doing incorrect. Screenshot: http://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/57676/screenshots/broketoolbar.png

The code:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    // TableViews that wish to utilize tableView footers/headers should override this method.

    UITableView *aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    aTableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    aTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    aTableView.delegate = self;
    aTableView.dataSource = dataSource;

    self.tableView = aTableView;
    self.view = tableView;
    [aTableView release];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
    [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;
    CGRect mainViewBounds = self.view.bounds;
    [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(mainViewBounds),
                                 CGRectGetMinY(mainViewBounds) + CGRectGetHeight(mainViewBounds) - (toolbarHeight * 2.0),
                                 CGRectGetWidth(mainViewBounds),
                                 toolbarHeight)];
    [self.view insertSubview:toolbar aboveSubview:self.tableView];
    [toolbar release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

because self.view is tableView onto which you added toolbar.